# C# можно ли к классу обратиться как к коллекции?

Tags: c#, классы, статические-члены

Есть задание: Написать пример класса для использования его в цикле `foreach(var i in MyClass)`.

Но это получается, мы буквально обращаемся к классу как какому-то массиву. Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Реализовать `IEnumerable` и все, что с ним связано.

Comment: Да, идея и вправду хорошая, но чтобы обратиться из такого цикла прямо к классу, нужно чтобы класс был статическим, а стат. классы не реализовывают интерфейсы

Comment: Если у вас в проекте все на стат. классах в проекте, то значит вы делаете что-то не так. И это не идея, это основной принцип того, что вы хотите.